# Set puppeteer window size when running not headless, but via console

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I was trying every solution I found, but couldn't set my Chromium window size (nor viewport) to any other than 800x600. I am running it on Debian server via SSH. I know there are similar questions with answers already, but these answers aren't working for me at all.

These are 2 options that I found combined:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox','--window-size=1920,1080']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page._client.send('Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride');

  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  })

  await page.goto('https://example.com',{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.screenshot({path: 'test.png'});

  browser.close();
})();
```

But it simply doesn't work. It does in `--headless` mode, but not in `normal` mode.
The screenshot is always 800x600, even when I set the numbers to lower than that. Any ideas why? Please note that the system is a server one, without X11.

Comment: I have no idea, it's a OVH VPS, you think it's that? but why can't i set it to for example 500x400 then? I don't think the resolution is a problem. xrandr returns "can't open display"

Comment: My bad I misread part of your question. Check out the docs defining the dependencies you need to install: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix

Comment: as I said already, if I wouldn't meet dependencies, I would get an error while running Chromium, so your answer is kinda ... not in the target :)

Comment: im getting same issue.. not found any resolutions.. always default size, tried all the 'solutions; online it still 800x600

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation on dependencies for your operating system:

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix

Install the requirements listed there and try again.

Comment: I did. Without that it wouldn't even run.

Comment: I'm really confused now. Are you trying to run a browser in non-headless mode over SSH?

Comment: yes, why not? I guess you don't know how it works :) why do you think it needs x11 libs? and it does run in non-headless mode, just only in 800x600